# pdf TOC creator for large files upwards of 120MB?

Tags: pdf

I used to use jPDFbookmark's bookmarks feature to create/adjust tables of contents for PDf files, and it worked perfectly well to that end until I input 130MB file and it was no longer functional, constantly re-loading and glitching out.

I thought I would head here and ask if anyone knew of a PDF editor made of stronger stuff,  and of course, one that can provide the same bookmarking feature. (aside from Adobe Acrobat)